swiftUI: Value of type 'AVCapturePhoto' has no member 'livePhotoMovieFileURL'
    try await PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges {
         let creationRequest = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()
         creationRequest.addResource(with: .photo, data: imageData, options: nil)
                        
                        // Add live photo video if available
                        if self.isLiveModeEnabled,
                           let movieURL = photo.livePhotoMovieFileURL {
                            print("Adding live photo video data")
                            let options = PHAssetResourceCreationOptions()
                            options.shouldMoveFile = true
                            creationRequest.addResource(with: .pairedVideo,
                                                      fileURL: movieURL,
                                                      options: options)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                self.error = error
            }
        }
    }

I cant get it right, was trying to add live picture, but it kept saying:

Value of type 'AVCapturePhoto' has no member 'livePhotoMovieFileURL'


How do you drfines/initialised the photo object ?

According to your error, you are using AVCapturePhoto with livePhotoMovieFileURL,
where the docs says you should use AVCapturePhotoSettings,
see Capturing and Saving Live Photos and
AVCapturePhotoSettings
